# Sublime Text 2 Build System

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I managed to get this build system doing the trick for me:

```
{
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "cmd": ["g++", "${file}"],

 "variants":
 [
  {
   "name": "Run",
   "shell": true,
   "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   "cmd": ["start", "a.exe"]
  }
 ]
}
```

But I don't want the shell to close once if finishes. I want it to display a message like "Build process complete. Press any key to exit...". Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I found out that adding a

```
while(true){}
```

to the end of the file makes it not close. Still waiting for a better solution tho.